# R - transform (period) long-format timeseries to wide format hourly timeseries

Tags: r, merge, time-series, fuzzyjoin

I would like to transform the following data frame into a wide format hourly timeseries with zero as padding if there is no value. Essentially I want to transform a dataframe with start/endperiod into a hourly timeseries:

```
   structure(list(AffectedAssetMask = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("A_1", "A_2", 
    "A_3", "A_4", "A_5"), class = "factor"), EventStart = structure(c(1525737600, 
    1525723200, 1525982400, 1525694400, 1525651200, 1525636800, 1525723200, 
    1525662000, 1525658400, 1525654800, 1525651200, 1525662000, 1525662000
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Rome"), EventStop = structure(c(1525748399, 
    1525737599, 1526155199, 1525723199, 1525694399, 1525651199, 1525809599, 
    1525665599, 1525661999, 1525658399, 1525654799, 1525665599, 1525665599
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "Europe/Rome"), UnavailableCapacity = c(150.95, 
    154.742, 115, 172.342, 198.163, 172.342, 115, 197, 281, 330, 
    340, 197, 197)), row.names = c(NA, -13L), class = "data.frame")
```

output:

```
AffectedAssetMask EventStart EventStop UnavailableCapacity
A_1 2018-05-08 02:00:00 2018-05-08 04:59:59 150.950
A_1 2018-05-07 22:00:00 2018-05-08 01:59:59 54.742
A_2 2018-05-10 22:00:00 2018-05-12 21:59:59 115.000
A_3 2018-05-07 14:00:00 2018-05-07 21:59:59 172.342
A_3 2018-05-07 02:00:00 2018-05-07 13:59:59 198.163
A_3 2018-05-06 22:00:00 2018-05-07 01:59:59 172.342
A_4 2018-05-07 22:00:00 2018-05-08 21:59:59 115.000
A_5 2018-05-07 05:00:00 2018-05-07 05:59:59 197.000
A_5 2018-05-07 04:00:00 2018-05-07 04:59:59 281.000
A_5 2018-05-07 03:00:00 2018-05-07 03:59:59 330.000
A_5 2018-05-07 02:00:00 2018-05-07 02:59:59 340.000
A_5 2018-05-07 05:00:00 2018-05-07 05:59:59 197.000
A_5 2018-05-07 05:00:00 2018-05-07 05:59:59 197.000
```

The last two entries are not my error, but sometimes the data includes double entries with the same value, but I think with "unique" I should be able to filter them out.

more data info:

```
> str(df1)
'data.frame':   13 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ AffectedAssetMask  : Factor w/ 5 levels "A_1","A_2","A_3",..: 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 5 5 5 ...
 $ EventStart         : POSIXct, format: "2018-05-08 02:00:00" "2018-05-07 22:00:00" "2018-05-10 22:00:00" "2018-05-07 14:00:00" ...
 $ EventStop          : POSIXct, format: "2018-05-08 04:59:59" "2018-05-08 01:59:59" "2018-05-12 21:59:59" "2018-05-07 21:59:59" ...
 $ UnavailableCapacity: num  151 155 115 172 198 ...
```

I need the data in a wide format style and instead of having the EventStart/EventStop period a hourly index with the same value for each hour and if its not included zero as value.

To transform it into wide format:

```
library(reshape2)

#cast long-format data into wide-format
dcast(df1,  EventStart + EventStop ~ AffectedAssetMask, value.var = "UnavailableCapacity", fun.aggregate = mean)
```

The format is fine, but instead of EventStart/EventStop I need a hourly continuous timeseries with zero as "fill".

I'm able to create an empty dataframe in my desired format:

```
  startPeriod<-as.POSIXct(strptime("01/05/2018 00:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
  endPeriod<-as.POSIXct(strptime("30/05/2018 00:00:00", "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S"))
  #create monthly hourly sequence
  dataseq <- seq(startPeriod,endPeriod,by = 3600)
  list<-unique(df1$AffectedAssetMask)
  NROW<-as.numeric(length(dataseq))
  OverallDataFrame<-as.data.frame(matrix(0,NROW,length(list)))
  names(OverallDataFrame)<-list
  rownames(OverallDataFrame) <- dataseq
```

The target output table should be something like this:

```
                      A_1 A_2 A_3     A_4 A_5
2018-05-06 18:00:00   0   0   0       0   0
2018-05-06 19:00:00   0   0   0       0   0
2018-05-06 20:00:00   0   0   0       0   0
2018-05-06 21:00:00   0   0   0       0   0
2018-05-06 22:00:00   0   0 172.342   0   0
2018-05-06 23:00:00   0   0 172.342   0   0
2018-05-06 00:00:00   0   0 172.342   0   0
2018-05-07 01:00:00   0   0 172.342   0   0
2018-05-07 02:00:00   0   0 198.163  340  0
2018-05-07 03:00:00   0   0 198.163   0   330
2018-05-07 04:00:00   0   0 198.163   0   281
2018-05-07 05:00:00   0   0 198.163   0   197
```

The csv file where the data is from, is around 8-9 Megabyte, a for loop takes too long. Some people suggest fuzzyjoin and fuzzy_left_join with the "match_fun" parameter, other a function to check if the index is in the intervall, unfortunately I'm kinda lost.

Thank you very much!